# What are the options of sending the same data to two independent consumers on the same machine via UDP?

Tags: networking, udp

Suppose I have a producer located on one machine and two independent consumers on the other. Consumers share the same IP. I want my data to be sent via WiFi and I want to avoid sending the same packages twice: I mean I want the packages to be replicated as late as possible -- either on router or on destination machine.

I managed to find these options:

1) Just use different ports -- in this case everything will be sent twice, but at least all consumers will get their copy of data.

2) Try to use `SO_REUSEPORT` -- without multicast this will make only one of two consumers get the packages.

3) Use multicast (with `SO_REUSEADDR`) -- I guess it is the only solution for my problem, and the packages will be replicated by router, not publisher.

I know, that there are messaging libraries and frameworks, which are supposed to be responsible for marshaling and routing, but I need "pure" UDP solution with maybe some simple logic upon it. I am not sure if I am correct with options that I mentioned, and I don't know whether there exists any more simple and suitable solution.

Comment: To send a single packet to multiple recipients, you use multicast. That is the exact reason we have multicast. The router does not replicate packets. The single packet gets sent to every host.

Comment: There is no such thing as "pure" UDP, which is a transport-layer protocol. The transport protocol rides inside the network protocol, e.g. IP. UDP does not care if IP uses unicast or multicast. It is unaware of how the network protocol sends it. The network protocol uses a data-link protocol, e.g. ethernet, and it doesn't care which one.

Comment: @RonMaupin From wiki: Multicast uses network infrastructure efficiently by requiring the source to send a packet only once, even if it needs to be delivered to a large number of receivers. The nodes in the network (typically network switches and routers) take care of replicating the packet to reach multiple receivers such that messages are sent over each link of the network only once.

You mean there is no such "optimization"?

Comment: Routers do not duplicate packets. An ethernet switch will flood the frame to all interfaces, but it does not actually replicate it, and a Wi-Fi AP will send it only once, although it must be sent at the lowest possible speed so that all Wi-Fi clients can hear it. Some WAPs can be set to replicate them as unicast to avoid that problem, but then it does a replication that takes a while.

Comment: In any case, UDP does not even know that it is sent either via unicast or multicast. The only difference is that only the host with the unicast address will process the unicast packet, even if it has been sent to all hosts, while any host subscribing to the multicast group will process a packet addressed to the multicast group.

Comment: @RonMaupin If I send the same package to several unicast addresses, there are as many packages in the network, as there are recipients, and if I send a multicast package, then there is only one instance of the package, which all hosts subscribed to that multicast group can get?

Comment: Correct. On any single link, you only have the one multicast packet sent, but you would need to serially send multiple unicast packets across the link. That was the entire point of multicast. It does not use the bandwidth that unicast uses (except, or course, in the case of a WAP that is configured to replicate multicast as unicast packets).

Comment: @RonMaupin Thank you very much for an explanation!

Answer (score 0):

As people told you in the comments, one popular and efficient solution to you problem (one publisher multiple subscribers over network, aka pubsub) is to send UDP datagrams to a [multicast IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast). The listeners must join that IP multicast group in order to tell the intermediate routers to forward those datagrams.

You can code it up yourself, there are plenty of examples elsewhere.

In a production setting, however, I recommend against reinventing the wheel along with associated mistakes. Have a look at existing solutions, such as [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/). It supports this messaging pattern of one publisher to multiple subscribers using UDP/IP multicast but with a nice interface, cross-language compatibility and much more. See [Publish/Subscribe example in Python](https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html).

Comment: In what way is using UDP multicast 'reinventing the wheel'?